# How to get the image response from a Flask api server and then display it in a react application

Tags: reactjs, api, flask, request, axios

The data field of the response gives the image file.

The python file in flask server has the following response code:

```
flask.send_file(loc_dir+res+".png", attachment_filename=res+".png", as_attachment=true)
```

To get the response in reactjs I am using:

```
var x = new Buffer(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64');
        console.log(x);
        this.setState({
            image_url: 'data:image/png;base64,'+x,
            gotGraph: true
        })
```

**PS**: I am sure that I get right image response as I getting a image when using Postman. 
[image]

**Edit**:

```
await axios.post('http://ec2-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/contrib/', {"url": "https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq"}, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'responseType': 'arraybuffer'
    }}).then(response => {
        var x = new Buffer(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64');
        console.log(x);
        this.setState({
            image_url: 'data:image/png;base64,'+x,
            gotGraph: true
        })
    })
```

Comment: Can you show how you are making an API call?

Comment: I think your response image is in base64 format, right

Comment: you can convert your buffer to image in backend side and pass image link as response in front-end

Comment: @AkhilAravind No it is the raw data that I am receiving

Comment: @PrakashKarena How can I do that? Can you give the resource where I can find the steps.

Comment: @Freddy I have now added in the question

Comment: @PrakashKarena I want to embed the image in my UI after receiving the image.

Comment: loc_dir+res+".png" dose this return your image path ??? from backend. check this and let me know what is out put of loc_dir+res+".png"  only

Comment: This is absolute madness. You need to send that file over the line with the propper file type headers and just display it as an <img src="" /> like the web was designed to be used