# Sending a file from Flask using send_file to a React frontend returns a string of weird characters

Tags: reactjs, flask

In my current program, the user selects a file in react, which is sent to flask as such

```
return axios
        .post(`http://localhost:5000/time`, data, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
        })
        .then(res => {
            this.onReturnProcessed(res);
            return res
    });
  }
```

and recieves data from flask as such

```
onReturnProcessed = res =>{
    console.log((res.data))
    this.setState({img:res.data})
    this.setState({ImgReturned:true})
    
    
  }
```

The Flask backend takes these files, and makes them a numpy array, and then a PIL Image object. It then saves the Image object to the Flask folder as such

```
img = Image.fromarray((np.uint8(cm(img)*255)))
img.save("./thenewimg.png")
```

Flask then sends the file to the react frontend

```
return send_file('./thenewimg.png',mimetype = 'image/png',as_attatchment=True)
```

The problem is that when React renders the file sent by flask

```
render(){
<div>
<img src = {this.state.img}/>
</div>
}
```

it is unable to interpret the file, and displays nothing except the file icon in the corner. When the file sent by flask is logged, it outputs many characters like ���}>�{���o��n�_����|��t����Jm~�\Ӳ���. I'm not sure how to change the file on the python backend so that react can interpret it and display it. Otherwise, I'm not sure how to change the frontend to display an image made in python.

This worked

```
@app.route('/img/<filename>',methods = ['GET'])
def give(filename):
    filen = './UPLOADS/'+filename+'.png' 
    return send_file(filen)
```

Comment: @momoin what is returned when you call `console.log(typeof this.state.img);`?

Comment: thats odd, I get string when I do that. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what is happening here is you are assigning `res.data` to your `img` variable. `res.data` is not the image itself that is assigned to `var`, but instead its base64 representation. This is why you are seeing the weird characters instead of the actual image.

An easier way to accomplish what you want might be to send back the URL of the image, not the image itself. This way you can store the image URL in your string, and then present the image like so:

```
console.log(this.state.img); // <-- this now returns 'https://whateveryourapiaddris.com/img/ID'

...

<img src={this.state.img} />
```

This means that you will need to create a separate flask route that will ingest the image ID that you assign to the image, and return the corresponding image using `send_file` at that end point.

---

Related questions:

- [How to get the image response from a Flask api server and then display it in a react application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59857001/14198287)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/bifsrt/display_image_from_flask_send_file_function/

Comment: Ok. I did this, and the file is correctly transferred. However, now I am curious, I have to use a new route every time i send the image if I want to update the route, is this normal? Is there a way to update the route?

Comment: @momion good stuff, I know that was probably not the answer you wanted to hear but I think you made a good decision with re-engineering your data flow. With Flask, you'll want to look into using dynamic routes, e.g., `@app.route('/api/img/<filename>', methods=['POST'])` so that way, you only need one route and all you need to pass to the user when they upload / fetch an image, is that very same file name that was generated when the image was uploaded.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I was thinking of creating a new file in the flask folder every time the program is run. Then when someone calls the route with that filename as the special string, it returns the file.  Does that sounds good?

Comment: Sounds like a cool project. Yes, you'll want two routes. (1) for uploading, as you described in your OP, and (2) another for fetching, as you described in your last comment. The second fetch route shouldn't make a new file each time it is called, it should simply return the image with `send_file`. The first route will be the one that posts the file. Let me know if that is clear! If not, I'm happy to help you with another question!

Comment: Hey, do you know if its possible to save a variable in a flask route and keep it there? Right now, my react frontend takes in a file and sends that file to the flask backend, which turns it into a numpy array and processes it, and saves the processed img as a png. Then, another flask route returns the processed png file. Im curious whether or not its possible to save the numpy array in a route, so it can be quickly accessed by flask for further processing when called upon by react. Please let me know what you think if you have time.

Comment: To clarify, you want the Flask route to return an array of image names. Is this correct? Are there any limiting factors for what images it should return?

Comment: I just realized I was thinking incorrectly, sorry. I solved my issue.

Comment: I posted a question if you have time to answer it. Here is the link. Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63851789/add-a-circle-when-clicking-on-an-img-in-react

Comment: Hi @momion would you mind sharing the code? Right now, I am using send_file('output.mp4', as_attachment=True), but I am get a ReadableStream in response.

Comment: @momoin feel free to edit my answer with your complete MRE if you feel that would be helpful for @jsdbt!

Comment: @momion You are sending a GET request? I am still getting the characters in the output (as in the OP). react code `axios.get("http://localhost:5000/vid/outputx").then(res => {console.log(res.data)})`    Flask  `@app.route('/vid/<filename>', methods=["GET"])
@cross_origin()
def get_s3(filename):
         path = filename + '.mp4'
         return send_file(path)`

Comment: ^Ignore. Solved this. I needed to just pass the `/vid/<filename>` as `src` i.e. <video src='/vid/outputx'></video> .

Comment: Hey, do you know if its trivial to transfer a react-flask web app (just a group of files pretty much) onto an AWS server and a website? Do you recommend any tutorials for this?

Comment: What AWS server type would you recommend for making my react-flask app into a website?

Comment: I just used their ec2 micro, it works well for testing and small deployments. But really it depends on how many users you expect to access your website concurrently.