# Add a circle when clicking on an img in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to make a program that adds a circle to an image when you click. When you click on (x,y) a circle will appear at (x,y) with radius 10. I'm not sure how to do some meta-programming type thing to be able to have N amount of circles in react. Ideally i could do this

```
for (let i = 0; i<N;i++){
<circle thingy x=Xs[i] y = Ys[i]/>
}
```

Then it would auto update whenever the image is clicked, and add a circle. So if you click 10 times, there would be 10 circles, and if you click one more time, one more circle would immediately appear.

Comment: Your questions has nothing to do with react. Attach click listener, when a user clicks, read coordinates. If it is within div, that would wrap your image, create absolutely positioned div on the clicked place with some border-radius. Save x/y relative to parent's size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need to do is listen for the clicks on an SVG and then add circles at the coordinates where those clicks occur. Something like this will work:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
  const [circles, setCircles] = useState([]);

  const getClickCoords = (event) => {
    // from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29296049/14198287
    var e = event.target;
    var dim = e.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = event.clientX - dim.left;
    var y = event.clientY - dim.top;
    return [x, y];
  };

  const addCircle = (event) => {
    // get click coordinates
    let [x, y] = getClickCoords(event);

    // make new svg circle element
    // more info here: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_circle.asp
    let newCircle = (
      <circle
        key={circles.length + 1}
        cx={x}
        cy={y}
        r="20"
        stroke="black"
        strokeWidth="1"
        fill="red"
      />
    );

    // update the array of circles; you HAVE to spread the current array
    // as 'circles' is immutible and will not accept new info
    let allCircles = [...circles, newCircle];

    // update 'circles'
    setCircles(allCircles);
  };

  console.log(circles);

  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>Big Pythagoras Pizza</h1>
      <h2>Click to add pepperoni:</h2>
      <ClickableSVG onClick={addCircle}>
        {/* This loads your circles in the circles hook here */}
        {circles}
      </ClickableSVG>
    </Container>
  );
}

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  hieght: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

const ClickableSVG = styled.svg`
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url('https://storage.pizzapizza.ca/phx2/ppl_images/category/en/2x/create_your_own_5.png');
  & * {
    /* Block your circles from triggering 'add circle' */
    pointer-events: none;
  }
`;
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-pepperoni-pizza-8dffl

---

Related questions:

- [How to get the click coordinates relative to SVG element holding the onclick listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261304/how-to-get-the-click-coordinates-relative-to-svg-element-holding-the-onclick-lis)