# How to get coordinates when clicking on the image in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an image in a React application, in the future images from cameras will be displayed there. the task is to get the coordinates of the clicked place by clicking on the image. as if we are clicking on a target in the image.

[image]

I've tried using `const coordnates = [e.clientX, e.clientY]` but I get screen coordinates not the

Comment: I have formatted your post, but it also seems like there is some info missing in your post. Use the [edit] link to add additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that you're looking for this: [Find mouse position relative to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234256/find-mouse-position-relative-to-element). ([`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect))

But there are plenty options that you can use for example [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map).

Comment: thanks for the answer. really helped. Perhaps you can help solve this problem. that when you click on the image on the image, the place of the click will appear in the form of a goal (as in the picture)

Comment: First think that comes to my mind is to set `position: relative` to the wrapper element and then create listener to `onClick` and create for example `<svg>` in with following css: `position: absolute; top: [valueFromClick]; left: [valueFromClick];`. But there's definitely a easier approach.

**Edit:** And here it is - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63852077/19147494 (that's what you're looking for)

Comment: Thanks, @Andrej. Thanks to your help everything worked out!