# Adding dots to .jpg in React Application

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface

I have built an app in React that allows the user to upload a .jpg image. However, I now want to add functionality that allows the user to click on the image, and a small red dot will appear. The user should be able to click four times and have four different red dots on the screen, where further clicks out not add any more dots. And if the user clicks on one of the 'Edit' buttons, it should clear out the coordinates listed, as well as the dot.

How would I go about refactoring my code in order to accomplish this? Below are both my .css and .js files. Thank you very much!

App.css

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.empty-div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.coords-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.coords {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.coords2 {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.text-box-container button {
  margin-left: 5px;
};

.input-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.input-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.input-container label {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.input-container input {
  margin-left: 5px;
}


.input-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
   grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.input-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.input-container label {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.input-container input {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.clear-button-container {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.edit-button {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.dropdown-container {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.image-container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Coords.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import './App.css';

const Grid = ({ coordinates, clearFields, handleDropdownChange, handleInputChange, handleEdit, handleMarkerClick  }) => {

  return (
    <div className="input-grid">
      <div className="input-container">
        <label htmlFor="x1">x1:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="x1"
          value={coordinates.x1}
          onChange={(e) => handleInputChange('x1', e.target.value)}
        />
        <button className="edit-button"  onClick={() => handleEdit('x1')}>Edit</button>
      </div>
      <div className="input-container">
        <label htmlFor="new1">Input 1:</label>
        <input type="number" id="new1" value={coordinates.new1} onChange={() => {}} />
      </div>
      <div className="input-container">
        <label htmlFor="x2">x2:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="x2"
          value={coordinates.x2}
          onChange={(e) => handleInputChange('x2', e.target.value)}
        />
        <button className="edit-button"  onClick={() => handleEdit('x2')}>Edit</button>
      </div>
      <div className="input-container">
        <label htmlFor="new2">Input 2:</label>
        <input type="number" id="new2" value={coordinates.new2} onChange={() => {}} />
      </div>
      <div className="input-container">
        <label htmlFor="y1">y1:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="y1"
          value={coordinates.y1}
          onChange={(e) => handleInputChange('y1', e.target.value)}
        />
        <button className="edit-button"  onClick={() => handleEdit('y1')}>Edit</button>
      </div>
      <div className="input-container">
        <label htmlFor="new3">Input 3:</label>
        <input type="number" id="new3" value={coordinates.new3} onChange={() => {}} />
      </div>
      <div className="input-container">
        <label htmlFor="y2">y2:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="y2"
          value={coordinates.y2}
          onChange={(e) => handleInputChange('y2', e.target.value)}
        />
        <button className="edit-button"  onClick={() => handleEdit('y2')}>Edit</button>
      </div>
       <div className="input-container">
        <label htmlFor="new4">Input 4:</label>
        <input type="number" id="new4" value={coordinates.new4} onChange={() => {}} />
      </div>
      <div className="clear-button-container">
        <button onClick={clearFields}>Clear All</button>
      </div>
      <div className="dropdown-container">
        <label htmlFor="mode">Mode: </label>
        <select id="mode" value={coordinates.mode} onChange={handleDropdownChange}>
          <option value="logarithmic">Logarithmic</option>
          <option value="linear">Linear</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Coordinates = () => {
  const [mousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [clickPosition, setClickPosition] = useState({ x: null, y: null });
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(null);
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({ x1: "", x2: "", y1: "", y2: "", mode: "linear"  });
  const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);
  const [dots, setDots] = useState([]);
  const imageRef = useRef(null);

  const handleInputChange = (field, value) => {
    setCoordinates({
      ...coordinates,
      [field]: value
    });
  };

  const handleEdit = (field) => {
    setCoordinates((prevCoordinates) => ({ ...prevCoordinates, [field]: '' }));
    setClickCount(0);
    setDots([]);
  };

 const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
    setMousePosition({ x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY });
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    const { x, y } = mousePosition;
    setClickCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);

    if (clickCount < 4) {
      setCoordinates((prevCoordinates) => ({
        ...prevCoordinates,
        [`x${clickCount + 1}`]: `(${x}, ${y})`
      }))

      setDots((prevDots) => [...prevDots, { x, y }]);
    }
  };

   const handleFileInputChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    setSelectedFile(file);
    setImageUrl(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    setDots([]);
    setClickCount(0);
  };

  const clearFields = () => {
    setCoordinates({
      x1: "",
      x2: "",
      y1: "",
      y2: "",
      new1: "",
      new2: "",
      new3: "",
      new4: "",
      mode: coordinates.mode
    });

    setClickCount(0);
    setDots([]);
  };

  const handleDropdownChange = (event) => {
    setCoordinates({
      ...coordinates,
      mode: event.target.value
    });
  };
  
   return (
   <div className="container">
      <div className="file-upload">
        <label htmlFor="file-input">Upload Image:</label>
        <input type="file" id="file-input" onChange={handleFileInputChange} />
      </div>
      <div className="image-container">
        {imageUrl && (
          <div className="image-overlay">
            <img
              src={imageUrl}
              alt="uploaded"
              onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
              onClick={handleClick}
              ref={imageRef}
            />
            {dots.map((dot, index) => (
              <div
                key={index}
                className="red-dot"
                style={{ left: dot.x, top: dot.y }}
              ></div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="empty-div"></div>
      <div className="coords-container">
        <p className="coords">X: {mousePosition.x}</p>
        <p className="coords2">Y: {mousePosition.y}</p>
      </div>
         <Grid
      coordinates={coordinates}
      clearFields={clearFields}
      handleDropdownChange={handleDropdownChange}
      handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
      handleEdit={handleEdit}
    />
  </div>
);
};

export default Coordinates;
```

Edit: this is the exact functionality I would like to have in my application, is there a way to refactor with the code I've got?

[Add a circle when clicking on an img in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63851789/add-a-circle-when-clicking-on-an-img-in-react)